PySpark FuzzyWuzzy UDF Causing Timeout Errors on Small Dataset / TimeoutError when filtering columns with Fuzzy Wuzzy similarity scores in PySpark
I'm working on a PySpark script to calculate similarity scores between columns using FuzzyWuzzy. I've defined a UDF for this purpose and used a for loop to iterate over columns specified in a metadata table, storing the similarity scores in the same DataFrame.
Here's the UDF I defined:
similarity_udf = F.udf(lambda x, y: fuzz.ratio(x, y), IntegerType())

I have a metadata table that lists the column pairs for which I need to compute similarity scores. Here's the simplified code:
meta_data = [
    ('column1', 'column2'),
    ('column3', 'column4'),
    # More column pairs
]
 
for col1, col2 in meta_data:
    df = df.withColumn(f'{col1}_{col2}_similarity', similarity_udf(F.col(col1), F.col(col2)))

After calculating the similarity scores, I filter the DataFrame to show scores greater than 95 for all similarity columns. However, when I run show() or count(), or try to load the data into Snowflake, I encounter a timeout error:
PythonException:
An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Lib\socket.py", line 709, in readinto
    raise
TimeoutError: timed out


There are only 8 records in the DataFrame.
I tried changing the Spark session configuration, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Technologies and versions:

Python 3.11.6
Java version "1.8.0_371"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_371-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.371-b11, mixed mode)
PySpark version 3.5.0
Using Scala version 2.12.18, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_371

Questions:

Is my approach of using a for loop to iterate over column pairs and apply the UDF correct in PySpark?
Why might the show() and count() operations cause a timeout even with such a small dataset?
Are there any best practices or alternative methods for calculating and filtering similarity scores across multiple column pairs in PySpark?
How can I debug or resolve this timeout issue to successfully load data into Snowflake?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Not sure what could be the issue. fuzzywuzzy has a new home with
a new package name thefuzz.
Maybe first try to read a csv file with data and write to a file.
If the above workflow works then it implies your problem lies
with interfacing with snowflake.
https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz
pip install thefuzz
Following code works on small data.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from thefuzz import fuzz


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

data = [
    (1, "apple", "apple", "banana", "banana"),
    (2, "orange", "orange juice", "grape", "grapefruit"),
    (3, "berry", "blueberry", "melon", "watermelon")
]

columns = ["id", "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

similarity_udf = F.udf(lambda x, y: fuzz.ratio(x, y), IntegerType())

meta_data = [
    ('column1', 'column2'),
    ('column3', 'column4'),
]

for col1, col2 in meta_data:
    similarity_col_name = f'{col1}_{col2}_similarity'
    df = df.withColumn(similarity_col_name, similarity_udf(F.col(col1), F.col(col2)))


df.show()

Output :
+---+-------+------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| id|column1|     column2|column3|   column4|column1_column2_similarity|column3_column4_similarity|
+---+-------+------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|  1|  apple|       apple| banana|    banana|                       100|                       100|
|  2| orange|orange juice|  grape|grapefruit|                        67|                        67|
|  3|  berry|   blueberry|  melon|watermelon|                        71|                        67|
+---+-------+------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+

